# Disabling automatic authorship suggestions on ResearchGate

Tags: privacy, notifications, researchgate

I would like to prevent ResearchGate from asking other users

> Did [MathMax](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/307633/mathmax) author this publication?

I have fetched all Account settings, but I could not find what I am looking for. Is there any such option?